# Django: How to override unique_together error message?

Tags: python, django, validation

In a model's Meta class, I define a unique_together. I have a ModelForm based on this model. When I call is_valid on this ModelForm, an error will automatically raised if unique_together validation fails. That's all good.

Now my problem is that I'm not satisfied with the default unique_together error message. I want to override it. How can I do that? For a field related error, I can easily do that by setting error_messages on the field parameters. But unique_together is a non field error. How can I override a non field error message?

Comment: I guess you better mark another answer as accepted instead of mine since Django 1.7 made important changes which also effects my answer.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

You can do [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/#considerations-regarding-model-s-error-messages) since Django 1.7

```
from django.forms import ModelForm
from django.core.exceptions import NON_FIELD_ERRORS

class ArticleForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        error_messages = {
            NON_FIELD_ERRORS: {
                'unique_together': "%(model_name)s's %(field_labels)s are not unique.",
            }
        }
```

Comment: An important note: You must import `NON_FIELD_ERRORS` from `django.core.exceptions`.

Comment: how to catch / detect this error in Django's views ?

Comment: @OmkarDeshpande, ModelForm already does this for you, and you just need to check `form.is_valid()` and rerender the template to display form errors.

Comment: I'm manually inserting data into db, by creating model instance in views.
I have handled it just using try and catch, else it gives error when we call model_obj.save() , on detecting duplicate record.

Comment: is there any proper way to do this ?

Comment: It would be great to be able to do the same for the modelserializer.

Answer (score 28):

**Update 2016/10/20**: See [jifeng-yin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/864688/jifeng-yin)'s even nicer answer below for Django >= 1.7

The nicest way to override these error messages might be to override the `unique_error_message` method on your model. Django calls this method to get the error message whenever it encounters a uniqueness issue during validation.

You can just handle the specific case you want and let all other cases be handled by Django as usual:

```
def unique_error_message(self, model_class, unique_check):
    if model_class == type(self) and unique_check == ('field1', 'field2'):
        return 'My custom error message'
    else:
        return super(Project, self).unique_error_message(model_class, unique_check)
```

Comment: This matches a solution I saw posted on a [blog](http://chriskief.com/2013/11/20/customize-djangos-unique_together-error-message/). But I have a question... why do we need to check if the `model_class` is of type `self`?

Comment: this is not really the "nicest" way anymore. at least for Django >= 1.7. See @jifeng.yin 's answer

Comment: @nuts: you can use jifeng.yin's answer only if you have a modalform. it was the case with the OP but may not be with future readers.

Comment: Why is jifeng.yin's solution 'nicer'? `unique_together` is set in the Model class, so it makes sense to also have the unique_error_message there as well. If forms then want to override the unique message separately, then they can do that. This method by Sam is preferred, for example for Django admin. There, you don't have a `ModelForm`. Creating a form just for this would be overkill. Plus, it's not just forms that would use this. Serializers (e.g. form `djangi-rest-framework`) would also use this method.

Answer (score 8):

For DRF serializers you can use this

```
from rest_framework import serializers


class SomeSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):


    class Meta:
        model = Some
        validators = [
            serializers.UniqueTogetherValidator(
                queryset=model.objects.all(),
                fields=('field1', 'field2'),
                message="Some custom message."
            )
        ]
```

Here is the original [source](https://gist.github.com/vaibhav-jain/91f49e8252ad4860b419868f704bbcf7).

Answer (score 2):

After a quick check, it seems that `unique_together` validation errors are hard-coded deep in `django.db.models.Model.unique_error_message` :

```
def unique_error_message(self, model_class, unique_check):
    opts = model_class._meta
    model_name = capfirst(opts.verbose_name)

    # A unique field
    if len(unique_check) == 1:
        field_name = unique_check[0]
        field_label = capfirst(opts.get_field(field_name).verbose_name)
        # Insert the error into the error dict, very sneaky
        return _(u"%(model_name)s with this %(field_label)s already exists.") %  {
            'model_name': unicode(model_name),
            'field_label': unicode(field_label)
        }
    # unique_together
    else:
        field_labels = map(lambda f: capfirst(opts.get_field(f).verbose_name), unique_check)
        field_labels = get_text_list(field_labels, _('and'))
        return _(u"%(model_name)s with this %(field_label)s already exists.") %  {
            'model_name': unicode(model_name),
            'field_label': unicode(field_labels)
        }
```

So maybe you should try to override this method from your model, to insert your own message !?

However, I haven't tried, and it seems a rather brutal solution ! But if you don't have something better, you might try...

Comment: Yes, it IS hardcoded. Hate it. The django team should have taken into consideration of the scenario of developer overriding non field error message.

Answer (score 0):

**Notice:** A lot had changed in Django since this answer. So better check other answers...

If what sebpiq is true( since i do not check source code), then there is one 
possible solution you can do, but it is the hard way...

You can define a validation rule in your form, [as it described here](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/#form-inheritance)

You can see [examples](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/validation/#cleaning-and-validating-fields-that-depend-on-each-other) of validation with more than one field, so by using this method, you can define a unique together check before standard django unique check executed...

Or the worst one, you can do a validation in your view before you try to save the objects...

Comment: this is not true anymore for Django>=1.7

Answer (score 0):

A better solution could be using [validate_unique](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.validate_unique) to raise a `ValidationError` to replace the error message:

```py
class ModelName(models.Model):
    ...

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ['field_1', 'field_2']
    
    def validate_unique(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().validate_unique(*args, **kwargs)

        if ModelName.objects.filter(field_1=self.field_1, field_2=self.field_2).exists():
            raise ValidationError(
                ...
            )
```

[Validating objects](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/models/instances/#validating-objects)

> Validating objects
>
> There are four steps involved in validating a model:
>
> 1. Validate the model fields - Model.clean_fields()
> 2. Validate the model as a whole - Model.clean()
> 3. Validate the field uniqueness - Model.validate_unique()
> 4. Validate the constraints - Model.validate_constraints()
>
> All four steps are performed when you call a model’s full_clean()
> method.
>
> When you use a ModelForm, the call to is_valid() will perform these
> validation steps for all the fields that are included on the form. See
> the ModelForm documentation for more information. You should only need
> to call a model’s full_clean() method if you plan to handle validation
> errors yourself, or if you have excluded fields from the ModelForm
> that require validation.

Answer (score -1):

You might take a look at overriding [django/db/models/base.py:Model._perform_unique_checks()](http://code.djangoproject.com/browser/django/tags/releases/1.2.3/django/db/models/base.py#L754) in your model.

In that method you can get the "original" errors:

```
    errors = super(MyModel, self)._perform_unique_checks(unique_checks)
```

-- then modify and return them upwards.

Comment: It is very risky to override "private" methods like this. You never know when they might change or even disappear