# Django How to prevent duplicate instances in database

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

I'm working with Django and I need to make sure I don't have identical items in the same table. 
I'm not entirely sure how one would go about making sure you don't enter the exact same information into a table twice. 
For example, if I'm a registering user who has to input their name and address, how do I make sure this exact same user, with the same name and address, isn't allowed to save their information twice.

Note that users are invited to input their information in a ModelForm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a [unique option](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/models/options/#unique-together). It would be implemented something like:

```
class someModel(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    address1 = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    class Meta:
        unique_together = ("name", "address1")
```

Comment: how would you get it to give back a specific phrase if this certain type of error occurs?

Comment: That would be my question too :D

Answer (score 0):

to change the unique together error message you can do this:
[Django: How to override unique_together error message?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3993560/django-how-to-override-unique-together-error-message)

```
class ArticleForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        error_messages = {
            NON_FIELD_ERRORS: {
                'unique_together': "%(model_name)s's %(field_labels)s are not unique.",
            }
        }
```