# Django Return Error when duplicates occur

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates

I'm using unique_together in the Meta Class in the model to prevent users to input their identical information into the database twice.

example:

```
class someModel(models.Model)
    name=models.CharField(max_length=100)
    address=models.CharField(max_length=100)
    class Meta:
        unique_together=("name","address")
```

When testing this out, I've noticed that it will return an error identical to the one returned when you leave a mandatory field empty. This is as a result of using {{field.errors}} in the template.

My question is how would you get it to give back a specific error (different than the mandatory field one) if this certain type of error occurs?

Comment: It should return a specific error without doing anything. Is unique together implemented at the DB level? I wonder if running syncdb would help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to have been discussed already here: [Django: How to override unique_together error message?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3993560/django-how-to-override-unique-together-error-message)

And just as a note:
The following section in Django docs go over custom form validation and error messages: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/validation/