# Is there another way to change the error message on a ModelForm for a validate_unique error?

Tags: python, django, django-forms

Disregarding the actual method I use below for parsing the error messages since it needs lots of improvement to make it more general-purpose, is parsing the error messages raised like this the only way of changing the error message displayed?

Specifically, I've removed one of the fields from a ModelForm.  When validate_unique is run I remove that field from validation as described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3757871/23972) on SO.  The error message that Django displays on the form when validate_unique is run says: 'X with this Y and Z already exists.' where Z is the field I manually removed from the ModelForm.  I want to change this error message because mentioning Z, the not-displayed field, is confusing to the user who has no way of changing Z on this form.

This feels fragile and hacky.

```
def validate_unique(self):
    exclude = self._get_validation_exclusions()
    exclude.remove('a_field_not_shown_on_form')

    try:
        self.instance.validate_unique(exclude=exclude)
    except ValidationError, e:
        if '__all__' in e.message_dict:
            for idx, err in enumerate(e.message_dict['__all__']):
                for unique_together in self.instance._meta.unique_together:
                    if 'a_field_not_shown_on_form' not in unique_together:
                        continue
                    if err.lower() == '{} with this {} and {} already exists.'.format(self.instance.__class__.__name__,
                                                                                      unique_together[0],
                                                                                      unique_together[1]).lower():
                        e.message_dict['__all__'][idx] = '{} with this {} already exists in {}'.format(self.instance.__class__.__name__,
                                                                                                       unique_together[0].capitalize(),
                                                                                                       self.instance.complex.name)

        self._update_errors(e.message_dict)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
from django.utils.text import capfirst

class YourModel(models.Model):

    # fields

    def unique_error_message(self, model_class, unique_check):
        opts = model_class._meta
        model_name = capfirst(opts.verbose_name)

        # A unique field
        field_name = self._meta.unique_together[0]
        field_label = capfirst(opts.get_field(field_name).verbose_name)
        # Insert the error into the error dict, very sneaky
        return _(u"%(model_name)s with this %(field_label)s already exists.") %  {
            'model_name': unicode(model_name),
            'field_label': unicode(field_label)
        }
```

Comment: Nudged me in the correct direction.  Thanks!  I combined that with this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6682124/23972