# How to display unique_together error message to user

Tags: python, django

Most of the questions I have come across that have to do with `unique_together` had to do with overriding the message.

I am uploading excel files and importing the data into the db. 
I want to display an error message to the user when the data being imported is a duplicate.

I haven't been able to find a way to display that message on a template even though it shows on the console.

models.py

```
class UserData(models.Model):
    GENDER_CHOICES = (
        ('Male', 'Male'),
        ('Female', 'Female'),
)

first_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
last_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
age = models.IntegerField()
gender = models.CharField(default='Male', choices=GENDER_CHOICES, max_length=6)
address = models.CharField(max_length=200)

class Meta:
    verbose_name_plural = 'User Data'
    unique_together = (('first_name', 'last_name', 'age', 'gender', 'address',),)

def __str__(self):
    return self.fullname()

def fullname(self):
    return self.first_name + self.last_name
```

the view

```
def save_to_db(request):
        if request.method == "POST":
             form = Importer(request.POST, request.FILES)
             if form.is_valid():
                 file = request.FILES['file']
                 import_data.delay(file)
                 file_name = request.FILES['file'].name
                 new_log = Log(action='file_upload', message=file_name)
                 new_log.save()
             return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('app:list'))
         else:
            return HttpResponseBadRequest()
    else:
        form = Importer()
    return render_to_response('Exstore/upload_form.html', {'form': form}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

PS: Customizing the error message is not a problem since there are answers like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3993560/django-how-to-override-unique-together-error-message)

Comment: I see you're using celery to process the uploaded file, so the file processing / content validation is not a part of the form's validation. The form will therefore be valid even if the file contains duplicate record, so - no error message about duplicate values will be displayed.

Comment: Ok I get it thanks!