# How to change unique_together error message in django model?

Tags: python, django, django-models

**Model:**

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    field1 = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    field2 = models.CharField(max_length=50)

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ('field1', 'field2')
```

**Error:** UNIQUE constraint failed: field1, field2

I want to change error mesaage to {'field2': 'This value is already exist'}

**OR**

How to override unique_error_message() in django model?

**I try this:**

```
def unique_error_message(self, model_class, unique_check):
    return ValidationError(message='My custom error message')
```

But didn't work.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Django: How to override unique\_together error message?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3993560/django-how-to-override-unique-together-error-message)

Comment: I don't use ModelForm and I want to change error message in model

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think one solution can be catching error in `save` method and raise whatever you want:

```py
from django.db import IntegrityError


class MyModel(models.Model):
    field1 = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    field2 = models.CharField(max_length=50)

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ('field1', 'field2')

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        try:
            return super().save(*args, **kwargs)
        except IntegrityError as err:
            if "unique constraint" in err.args[0]:
                # raise what you want
```